# How to ensure that multiple clicks on a single button don't duplicate the result?

Tags: java, android, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed a like button on post, and when it clicks, it adds 1 everytime. I only want once the user clicked the button, it counts only to one, but when it is clicked multiple times the count increases by the same user and which not supposed to happen?

I just want one click, one counter update by the same user, not anymore

how shall I proceed?

I am using the transactions in firestore to complete the operation

```
private void transactionlPostUserl1() {

        Log.d(TAG,"hello4");

        final DocumentReference PostUserRef = db.collection("users").document(PostAuthorID);


        db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {



                DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot2 = transaction.get(PostUserRef);
                long l11 = documentSnapshot2.getLong("l2");
                { transaction.update(PostUserRef, "l2", l11+1);


                    return null;
                }


            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {





                Log.d(TAG, "Transaction success: " + result);
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Log.w(TAG, "Transaction failure.", e);
                    }
                });



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the ID of every user who liked for every post and then check if that person already like it? Then you can just count the amount of people who liked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 boolean canClick = true;

        // inside the click event 
        if (canClick)
        canClick = false;

        // when the click event ends:
        canClick = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `btn.setEnabled(false);` & `btn.setEnabled(true);` to control multiple click